# Performing ANOVA in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

I have a data set as such:

[image]

How can I perform an ANOVA between each of the columns X0, X1 ... X6 in R using either anova or aov functions?

Comment: Without formal testing, it seems possible that variances among the seven groups may differ, so I suggest using the R procedure `oneway.test`. If significant differences are found among the groups, then use Welch 2-sample t tests _ad hoc_ to find which pairs of groups differ significantly. (Same as earlier Comment, but with typos corrected.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt to transcribe your data for input. You should proofread.

```
x0 = c(124, 106, 127, 151)
x1 = c(121, 120, 117, 129)
x2 = c(116, 112, 134, 125)
x3 = c(120, 129, 101, 123)
x4 = c(104, 123, 126, 142)
x5 = c(100, 112, 104, 114)
x6 = c(102, 116,  92, 109)
x = c(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)
gp = rep(0:6, each=4)

 stripchart(x ~ gp, pch="|", ylim=c(.5,7.5))
```

From the stripcharts, it seems that any differences among group means are
overwhelmed among the considerable variability within many of the groups.

[image]

```
oneway.test(x ~ gp)

        One-way analysis of means 
     (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and gp
F = 2.475, num df = 6.0000, denom df = 9.1428,
p-value = 0.1058
```

No significant differences among groups are found at the 5% level (P-value 11% > 5%).

An ordinary ANOVA, assuming equal variances in the seven groups, would have
denominator DF = 21. The considerably smaller denominator DF here (about 9)
attempts to correct for unequal group variances in your data.

*Note:* (1) Groups 1 and 6 do not overlap. If they stood alone, a Welch 2-sample t test would find them to have significantly different means. However, it it not
legitimate to "cherry-pick" the most extreme difference of two from among ${7\choose 2} = 21$ pairs for individual testing, when the overall ANOVA
test finds no significant differences. That would often lead to 'false discovery'.

(2) Out of curiosity, I ran a standard one-way ANOVA (assuming equal variances) for these data. There were no significant differences at the 5% level.

```
anova(lm(x ~ as.factor(gp)))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
as.factor(gp)  6 1711.4  285.23  1.9921 0.1125
Residuals     21 3006.8  143.18
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to transform the data in order to get it into the t.test and anova.